# unable to read object (Can't find variable error)

Tags: react-native, object, asyncstorage

In my below code, I stored an object in AsyncStorage in React Native, but I have a problem reading it inside {personValue}. I got

> Can't find variable personValue

Error. could you help me to run my code?

```
     const storeData = async () => {
    try {
      const newperson = JSON.stringify(person);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("@Key", newperson);
      alert(newperson);
    } catch (e) {
      
    }
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const personValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@Key");
      if (personValue !== null) {
        
        console.log(JSON.parse(personValue));
        return JSON.parse(personValue);
      }
    } catch (error) {
     
    }
```

in the console, I can see the object correctly in GetData method

P.S: I found the mistake I made. I parsed the wrong variable.

Comment: This code works fine. Make sure that the error you got is from these lines of code

Comment: Hi. I found my mistake. the issue was that I parse the wrong variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const personValue = await JSON.parse(AsyncStorage.getItem("@Key"));
      if (personValue !== null) {

        console.log(personValue);
        return personValue;
      }
    }
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: its not a good idea because the object has been parsed already